# Git pull auto merging instead of replacing

Tags: git, github

I currently have a website set up using composer and also have a mirror copy of the site for development.

I do all my work on the development site, `commit` and `push` my changes and then `pull` the repository on the live site.

I am fairly new to using Git, especially using Git bash and have previously used TortoiseHg which I found much simpler.

The problem:

If I run `composer update` on the development site, and then `pull` the changes to live, Git pull attempts to auto merge the changes. This means I have to go through the file and choose the incoming changes for each conflict.

Git Pull seems to be merging between the local files and the files that are being pulled in from the repository.

What I want to do is literally just pull the files onto my live site, replacing all of the files on it without any merges.

What command am I looking for here? I've tried to research the issue and cannot find the solution.

Comment: If you don’t do any work on live why are you getting conflicts?

Comment: because when i use git pull, it is trying to merge the old files with the new files and im not sure why

Comment: oh my god, i am a muppet. ive just realised that ive probably tried to change files on live and then pull the changes from dev

Comment: there shouldnt be any conflicts if live never changes and only dev is pulled in

Comment: great thinking! I thought the same